# iphone application send data to php

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xcode

have been figuring this for almost 2 weeks.. what I want is to post the "computedHeartRate.text" to a php file and display it to the screen

the heart rate is generated by a Wahoo product.

most of the code is copy from internet, im a fresh newbie of Xcode
this is what I've done so far:

```
        NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hb=%@",computedHeartrateLabel.text];
    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/123.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];



    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[urlData length]);
    NSLog(@"Your %@ ",computedHeartrateLabel.text);

    NSString *outputdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData
                                                 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Outputdata is %@",outputdata);


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(error==nil)
        NSLog(@"Error is nil");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error is not nil");
```

---

the output:

```
2013-10-22 11:46:58.762 WahooDemo[5820:907] Succeeded! Received 0 bytes of data
2013-10-22 11:46:58.763 WahooDemo[5820:907] Your 69 BPM 
2013-10-22 11:46:58.763 WahooDemo[5820:907] Outputdata is 
2013-10-22 11:46:58.773 WahooDemo[5820:907] Error is not nil
2013-10-22 11:47:00.245 WahooDemo[5820:907] Succeeded! Received 0 bytes of data
2013-10-22 11:47:00.245 WahooDemo[5820:907] Your 68 BPM 
2013-10-22 11:47:00.246 WahooDemo[5820:907] Outputdata is 
2013-10-22 11:47:00.255 WahooDemo[5820:907] Error is not nil
2013-10-22 11:47:01.246 WahooDemo[5820:907] Succeeded! Received 0 bytes of data
2013-10-22 11:47:01.246 WahooDemo[5820:907] Your 67 BPM 
2013-10-22 11:47:01.247 WahooDemo[5820:907] Outputdata is 
2013-10-22 11:47:01.256 WahooDemo[5820:907] Error is not nil
```

my php file:

```
<?php

echo "fsdseeetttttsd<br>";

echo "BHGHGH<br>";

$hb2 =@$_POST['hb'];

echo $hb2;
```

any help is appreciated..

Comment: you are sending it to a php file located on "localhost:8888". this is a problem from two reasons: 
1. localhost is the device you are using and the php file is not located on it.
2. port 8888 might not be open (exctually probebly are closed) on the iphone. so even if you had something such as "localhost/phpfile.php" on your iphone it won't work.
try using local ip like `192.168.1.X` http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/identify-network-hardware-ip-addresses-local-network.htm

Comment: thx. i'll try to fix this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/123.php"];
```

is probably what is causing the problem (localhost refers to the phone, not to your computer).  You should change that to the appropriate ip address.

More generally, you should actually pass a pointer for error and response in the first query so that you can see what happened:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```